# Forbidden Island: Can the navigator move another player 4 tiles for 2 actions / 6 for 3?

Tags: forbidden-island

The navigator's action is moving another player 2 tiles for 1 action - it does not specify once per turn. Does this mean he could move another player 3 or 4 tiles for 2 action points, or is there a rule/clarification about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the rulebook:

> The Navigator may move other players up to 2 adjacent tiles per action

As it states it's *per action* so yes you could repeat that same action 3 times. It's a very useful ability.

Comment: That's how I read it too, but wasn't sure if there was a consensus among the gaming community. Appears there is! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I interpreted the rules that way, since other player abilities like the Explorer are not limited that way. When we play, a navigator can use her ability multiple times per turn.